# How to Define a Protobuf Message for Dynamic JSON data for Javascript

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-node, protobufjs

I using then gRPC for inter micro service communication. Both the services are written in JavaScript. In the response of the gRPC call I need to send an array for JSON objects, Which contains the nested JSON objects also and data is dynamic in the JSON objects.

I have used the Struct for the definition but I am not getting the response properly. Any suggestion or guide how can I achieve the functionality.
Also I found that proto3 JSON is not supported for JS as found on this [link](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/1772tpAr3N4?pli=1)

Comment: You say "I have used the Struct for the definition but I am not getting the response properly." What specifically is the problem you are encountering with this?